# Adding spring to servlet just for validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, jsp, servlets

I am currently not using any frameworks (other than bootstrap) for my java-ee application. But i came across a problem in using server side validation for servlets. I am finding it difficult to implement validation like this
http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/
I could use request dispatcher, but I am not sure if it's the right way. 
So i wanted to ask is it advisable to use the spring framework just for the validation?
is there any way to convert my entire java application to use spring or should i build the application from the ground up again?

Comment: A good validation framework is java bean validation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html

Comment: well if you ever want to build from "scratch", Spring-Boot is a great way to bootstrap your app: http://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the validation, then I recommend to use JSR-303/349 Bean Validation 1.0/1.1. The default implementation is done by Hiberante-Validator (this is NOT the Hibernate-ORM project!). It is relative easy to use out of the box.

http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks a lot i think i'll use bean validation instead of spring since it would take some time to learn it